# How to pass Java exceptions from arrow flight server to client? (both using Java libraries)

Tags: apache-arrow

In the acceptPut call to accept data stream, I want to throw an exception at arrow flight server side which should be available to arrow flight client so that client can rethrow it for the cosumers of the client to get the actual exception.
Please suggest if there is any standard way of passing the exception details from arrow flight server to client?

What I was trying to do is use following code:
if "ex" is my custom exception then:

```
    String customException = objMapper.writeValueAsString(ex);
    ErrorFlightMetadata metadata = new ErrorFlightMetadata();
    metadata.insert("value", customException);
    ackStream.onError(new CallStatus(FlightStatusCode.INTERNAL, ex,
        "CustomException", metadata).toRuntimeException());
```

But on the arrow flight client side, when I run:

```
stream.getResult();
```

It throws the FlightRuntimeException exception with correct status code and description as I had set on the server side but ErrorFlightMetadata object is not present.

If ErrorFlightMetadata is not passed on from server to client, then what are the alternate options to send details of exception from server to client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this regard, Arrow Flight mirrors gRPC Java. While the CallStatus allows you to attach an exception, this is not mirrored to the client to avoid leaking details about the server to the client.

The simplest thing would be to stringify the exception and include it in the error message. So long as the traceback is not too long (several kilobytes), this works fine. (gRPC, the underlying transport, limits the size of metadata by default, and metadata are used to carry the error message.)

You can also attach custom key-value metadata to the error.

Currently (Arrow 4.0.0), this is not fully implemented: see [ARROW-12842](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-12842). (This was fixed for 5.0.0.) So for now, you must use gRPC's StatusRuntimeException directly, e.g. see this test case: [TestErrorMetadata.java](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/d07f30ada67780251e3f053aaf4dd32eb6450cec/java/flight/flight-core/src/test/java/org/apache/arrow/flight/TestErrorMetadata.java).

In the future, you'll be able to attach the metadata to the Flight error object as well:
https://arrow.apache.org/docs/java/reference/org/apache/arrow/flight/CallStatus.html#withMetadata-org.apache.arrow.flight.ErrorFlightMetadata-

In either case, note that the client may or may not display this information by default. This is more useful if you want to programmatically get the traceback on the client side and do something with it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When sending metadata key value pairs from server to client https://arrow.apache.org/docs/java/reference/org/apache/arrow/flight/CallStatus.html#withMetadata-org.apache.arrow.flight.ErrorFlightMetadata-, metadata that reaches client does not have any key value pairs. They are getting lost. Do you know what might be the root cause for it or am I missing something? If you have some sample programs which can show arrow flight server and client in Java passing along the error and filling metadata with key value pairs.

Comment: Hmm, it might actually be part unimplemented. I'll take a closer look and get back to you. What Arrow version are you using?

Comment: @pranjaljain See this test; you can use the gRPC StatusRuntimeException instead: https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/d07f30ada67780251e3f053aaf4dd32eb6450cec/java/flight/flight-core/src/test/java/org/apache/arrow/flight/TestErrorMetadata.java 
You can then directly customize the trailers, e.g. with this constructor: https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/StatusRuntimeException.html#StatusRuntimeException-io.grpc.Status-io.grpc.Metadata-

Comment: @pranjaljain FYI, a fix was merged targeting Arrow 5.0.0.